# How to extract authorization header from URL in Vue JS App

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have created a vue js app for frontend development.

In our case, we will be getting auth info in authorization header from some other web app.

I dont understand how can i fetch authorization header from URL.

I know we can fetch params from URL.

Can anyone please help me with this - How can i fetch authorization header from URL.

Thanks & Regards,
Jyoti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible for client-side JS to access headers in the request that initially loads the page. You can add headers to outbound requests *made* by client-side JS, but only the server getting the request has access to the headers. If it makes the information in that header available to the client, either as a cookie or in the source of the page, you can work with it, but depending on your application, that might be a security risk (e.g. for replay attacks).